# Instead of showing the latest posts, how to show the latest post from each category on the homepage in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have the code to display the latest posts on my website, but I wonder if there is a way to make a list of the latest posts, displaying only one post per category. Let's say I have 7 categories, so only 7 posts will be displayed on the page. What should I do?

```
<?php if ( ! is_single() ) { ?>
<div class="post-container">
<?php } ?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <?php
   //Post Title code

   //Post Thumbnail code

    //Post Content / Excerpt code

     //Post Meta code

</article> <!-- /post -->

<?php if ( ! is_single() ) { ?>
</div>
<?php

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy to add latest post from each category.

First of all get all the categories of blog by using below code:

```
$categories = get_categories();
```

Then use `foreach ( $categories as $category ) {}` to tell WordPress to run through each of these categories in turn and run the code inside the braces.

Now you need to define the arguments for your query. Inside the braces, add this:

```
$args = array(
    'cat' => $category->term_id,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
);
```

Next, insert your query, using the WP_Query class:

```
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>

    <section class="<?php echo $category->name; ?> listing">
        <h2>Latest in <?php echo $category->name; ?>:</h2>

        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

            $query->the_post();
            ?>

            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'category-listing' ); ?>>
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); ?>
                    </a>
                <?php } ?>

                <h3 class="entry-title">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </a>
                </h3>

                <?php the_excerpt( __( 'Continue Reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyfourteen' ) ); ?>

            </article>

        <?php } // end while ?>

    </section>

<?php } // end if

// Use reset to restore original query.
wp_reset_postdata();
```

This will display each category posts in your home page. Please try to use it and let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: man, you're fast... :) Yes this is the right approach for this issue, I can confirm this, since I've used it exactly in the same way. Good answer

Comment: Thanks @Angel Deykov